# Why are they sticking towards each other?

Tags: android, custom-lists

I am trying to get a simple custom list View and am struck as the elements are sticking to each other which looks worst than ever.I have created the program_list.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/TVIDC"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/TVNameC"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Date"
    android:id="@+id/TVDateC"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="0.00"
    android:id="@+id/TVAmountC"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the CustomList file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final Integer[] id;
private final String[] name;
private final Integer[] amount;
private final String[] date;


public CustomList(Activity context, Integer[] id, String[] name, Integer[] amount, String[] date) {
    super(context, R.layout.program_list, name);
    this.context = context;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.date = date;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null, true);
    TextView txtId = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVIDC);
    TextView txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVNameC);
    TextView txtAmount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVAmountC);
    TextView txtDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVDateC);


    txtId.setText(id[position]+"");
    txtName.setText(name[position]);
    txtAmount.setText(amount[position]+"");
    txtDate.setText(date[position]);


    return rowView;
}
}
```

Find solution fast, I am struck, wanna upload app on play store and refer to image for the major problem. Thank to everyone in advance and I have to write some silly details to remove the red box, don't think a lot about it because to post, I have to remove this box. Still this silly box hasn't gone. Hey stack overflow! It has gone mad.

This is causing problem:

[image: Its what coming]

But I want this:

[image: Good one]

Comment: Change your width from wrapcontent to match_parent for all the textview

Comment: Didn't work!! Suggest Something else.....

Comment: I did not do any changes in your layout and made a same program using your custom adapter it works fine for me

Comment: try cleaning your project and rebuilding it

Comment: Didn't work, is there any problem in my emulator? I use genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of your views to `android:layout_width="0dp"`. Also, I don't think you need this line `android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

The sum should be missing in the LinearLayout parent.

Replace

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_horizontal">
```

by

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_horizontal"
android:weightSum="4">
```